# Setting up box metadata for MediaSource to work

Tags: html5-video, mp4, h.264, media-source

Using mp4box to add h264 to a fragmented dash container (mp4)

Appending the m4s (dash) media segments.  Don't know how to preserve order in the box metadata and not sure if it can be edited when using mp4box.  Basically if I look at the segments this demo:

```
 http://francisshanahan.com/demos/mpeg-dash
```

there is a bunch of stuff latent in the m4s files that specify order.  Like the mfhd atom that has the sequence number.  Or the sidx that keeps the earliest presentation time (which is identical to the base media decode time in the tfdt).  Plus my sampleDuration times are zeroed in the sample entries in the trun (track fragment run).

Have tried to edit my m4s files with mp4parser without luck.  Wondering if somebody else has taken h264 and built up a MediaSource stream?